# what is my mistake in the code and why is that error for?

Tags: python

So basically I have to write a code which tells the user to input numbers (as variables I named them number1, number2, number3 ...) until I get the answer of zero once you add each number that they inputted then which the sum is equal to zero I should print how many numbers they inputted so the answer they got was zero, now the main thing is that I know how to write that code but there is an error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Solution.py", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit()
    NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

Comment: Plz provide your `code` in the question.

Comment: to get help and improve your code you should include your code here (instant explain that).also need to add your all Traceback error message

Comment: The message tells you exactly what the error is. It does not know what `sys` is. You did not import it, or otherwise defined it.

Comment: Is `import sys` in your code anywhere?

Comment: I edited you code but not yet accepted, I see a link to an image. Hope you can edit it so we can see it. Pleas post code not image.

Comment: if number1 + number2 + number3 + number4 == 0:
    print("4")
    sys.exit()

Comment: no, I didn't know I should import sys since this is my first time actually trying to use it

Comment: anyways thx all I wrote import sys and i got it correct so thx for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try using

from sys import *

and just use exit(0) when you want to sys.exit()

Comment: thx I got, thx for you help